# How to chain actions/animations together and delay their execution?

Tags: xna, c#, game-loop

I'm trying to build a simple game with a number of screens - 'TitleScreen', 'LoadingScreen', 'PlayScreen', 'HighScoreScreen' - each of which has it's own draw & update logic methods, sprites, other useful fields, etc. This works well for me as a game dev beginner, and it runs.

However, on my 'PlayScreen' I want to run some animations before the player gets control - dropping in some artwork, playing some sound effects, generally prettifying things a little. However, I'm not sure **what the best way to chain animations / sound effects / other timed general events is**.

I could make an intermediary screen, 'PrePlayScreen', which simply has all of this hardcoded like so:

```
Update(){
     Animation anim1 = new Animation(.....);
     Animation anim2 = new Animation(.....);
     anim1.Run();
     if(anim1.State == AnimationState.Complete)
          anim2.Run();
     if(anim2.State == AnimationState.Complete)
          // Load 'PlayScreen' screen
}
```

But this doesn't seem so great - surely their must be a better way? I then thought, 'Hey - an AnimationManager! That'd be awesome!'. But then that creeping OOP panic set in as I thought about it some more.

If I create the Animation in my Screen, then add it to the AnimationManager (which may or may not be a GameComponent hooked up to Update/Draw), how can I get 'back' to it? To signal commands like start / end / repeat? I'd still need to keep a reference to the object in my Screen so that I could still communicate with it once it's buried in the bosom of a List in my AnimationManager. This seems bad.

I've also tried using events - call 'Update' on all the animations in the PlayScreen update loop, but crucially all of the animations have a bool flag ('Active') which determines whether they should begin. The first animation has this set to 'true', all others 'false'. On completion the first animation raises an event, which sets animation 2's bool flag to true (and so it then runs). Once animation 2 is complete another 'anim complete' event is raised, and the screen state changes.

Considering the game I'm making is basically as simple as it gets I know I'm overthinking this... it's just the paradigm shift from web -> game development is making me break out in a serious case of the *stupids*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Basic Framework**

Here's my solution to this common problem. First let's choose a name for an *action that spans several frames*, such as an animation. I'll call it a `Process` which is the terminlogy I found in [this book](http://www.mcshaffry.com/GameCode/), but *don't* mistake it with the processes on your OS, it's a different concept. In this context, a process is *anything* that needs to be updated, possibly several times, before it completes.

I'll start by defining a base class for our process. Something as simple as this is enough (I kept the name as Process for consistency with the discussion above, but since .NET already has a class named like that, you might want to give it another name):

```
public abstract class Process
{
    public abstract void Update(float elapsed);
    public bool Finished { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's create a class that serves as a process queue. You add processes to this queue, and they get executed in turn. This is where my implementation differs from the one in the book above. In the book every process is updated every frame, but in this case I'll make them *sequential* instead, so that the second process only starts when the first one ends. Once again it's a simple class:

```
public class ProcessQueue
{
    public void Add(Process process)
    {
        _processQueue.Add(process);
    }

    public void Update(float elapsed)
    {
        if (_processQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            _processQueue[0].Update(elapsed);
            if(_processQueue[0].Finished)
            {
               _processQueue.RemoveAt(0); 
            }
        }
    }

    private readonly List<Process> _processQueue = new List<Process>();
}
```

And that's it, although you're free to add more methods, for example to clear the queue or to know how many processes are currently queued. Now just make your `Animation` class inherit from `Process` and chain them like:

```
// On startup
var processQueue = new ProcessQueue();

// Chain a few animations
processQueue.Add(new Animation(...));
processQueue.Add(new Animation(...));
processQueue.Add(new Animation(...));

// On Update
processQueue.Update(elapsed);
```

Note that you can create and chain all the processes you want before the game starts, because they only really start being executed when you call update for the first time on the queue.

When implementing the `Animation` class inheriting from `Process` make sure to set the `Finished` property to true when the animation ends, so that it will get removed from the queue.

*I think that probably already answers your question, but if you're interested in the subject, keep reading.*

---

**Bonus - Some Useful Processes!**

I might as well drop some useful types of processes for pretty much any type of game! Hopefully these will inspire you to make your own processes too.

First we have the `SleepProcess` which as the name implies, does nothing for a certain duration of time:

```
public class SleepProcess : Process
{
    public SleepProcess(float duration)
    {
        _duration = duration;
    }

    public override void Update(float elapsed)
    {
        _timer += elapsed;
        if(_timer >= _duration)
            Finished = true;
    }

    private float _timer;
    private readonly float _duration;
}
```

And sometimes you don't need a process that spans several frames - a single frame is enough. The following `GenericProcess` makes that easy:

```
public class GenericProcess : Process
{
    public GenericProcess(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public override void Update(float elapsed)
    {
        _action();
        Finished = true;
    }

    private readonly Action _action;
}
```

**Mixing Everything Together - An  Example**

Here's how you can use these processes. Let's say for instance that you would like to play animation A, wait 2 seconds, play animation B, and finally write a message to the debugger. By using the processes above you can implement this entire sequence as four lines of code:

```
processQueue.Add(new AnimationProcess(...));
processQueue.Add(new SleepProcess(2));
processQueue.Add(new AnimationProcess(...));
processQueue.Add(new GenericProcess(() => Diagnostics.Debug("Message")));
```

And the only thing you need to do is remember to call `Update` on the process queue. Can you see how powerful this concept can be when properly used? Pretty much *everything* in your game can be considered as a process!

**What About Looping?**

What if I wanted to take the example above and *make it loop* infinitely? Well, this too, is extremely simple to implement with this framework, using a sort of "delayed recursive" call. Just put the processes you want to loop inside a function, and then add a `GenericProcess` at the end that adds that calls that function once more:

```
void LoopProcesses()
{
    processQueue.Add(new AnimationProcess(...));
    processQueue.Add(new SleepProcess(2));
    processQueue.Add(new AnimationProcess(...));
    processQueue.Add(new GenericProcess(() => Diagnostics.Debug("Message")));

    // Call LoopProcesses again after all of the above are finished
    processQueue.Add(new GenericProcess(LoopProcesses));
}

// Call once to start looping
LoopProcesses();
```

Comment: Nice, I had this framework in a game I did once, but with the name of Event, instead of Process. To tell the truth, processes sounds way better for me, I just didn't mind the name in the time :D

Comment: @Gustavo-Gtoknu I like the name `Process` too, I think it describes the concept nicely! But I hate how it collides with `System.Diagnostics.Process` forcing me to deal with namespaces, so I usually change it to something else, like `GameProcess` or something.

Comment: This is great - thanks very much for the thorough reply. For multiple 'parallel sequences' of Actions would you recommend several ProcessQueues simply updated at the same time?

Comment: @codinghands That's the most simple way, yes! But once again that's a design decision with a lot of room for variation. There's even a very interesting thing you can do which is make your `ProcessQueue` class *itself* a `Process`, and give it two different modes of operation - sequence and parallel (although the name queue is no longer appropriate). Then you could just create a `ProcessQueue` (in parallel mode) and *add* your other `ProcessQueue`s (in sequence mode) to it, just like as any other process. This is basically the composite design pattern and allows many other tricks too :)

Comment: Proception! Baaarm! That's a great idea. I really need to read some game design architecture stuff, that wasn't immediately obvious at all. Going to give implementing this a shot right now. Thanks again!

Comment: @codinghands Don't feel ashamed, I only realized the benefits of treating the queue itself as a process yesterday, when speaking about the subject with a fellow game developer :) You're always learning new tricks in this business.

Comment: This works great! Just had one little thought though... say Animation2 needs to know something about Animation1 (e.g. the ending position of the sprite it animated). Any thoughts on how I could communicate this change?

Comment: @codinghands This will vary from situation to situation, but I don't think that dependency should be a responsibility of the queue. So I tend to add dependencies to the processes themselves. E.g. pass a reference to A to B's constructor. I think I know what you're trying to do though, but it's a bit hard to explain so compare what I will say with [this example](http://pastie.org/3740254). Basically, pass a reference to the *character* to the animation process, and use the reference to get the character's position **but on the first update, not in the constructor** (see example in link).

Comment: Ah-ha, a bit new to C# from Java, didn't know about the 'ref' keyword, which worked a charm.

Comment: @codinghands Just to clarify, you only need to use the `ref` keyword when trying to pass a a value type (i.e. `struct`, `enum` and *most* built-in types - except for `object`, `string` and `dynamic`) by reference. On the other hand, every `class`, `interface` or `delegate` is already a reference type so the keyword is not needed there.

Comment: Sure - just doing it with a test class and value types.

Comment: @DavidGouveia Just a small bit of info which you may already know: `ref` does have an effect when sending in a reference type of allowing you to repoint the reference. If you send in a reference to an object, and then set that reference to something else in your method, the calling method won't reflect that change (whereas it would reflect if a property of the passed in object had been changed). Passing by ref will mean that when the method gets back the reference you sent in may point at a totally different object.

Comment: @JeremyPridemore Thanks for the reminder, it's been a while since I've used a reference to a reference so I had already forgotten about it :)

Comment: I just want to reiterate again how astonishingly helpful this was. Using it now in Lua :)

Comment: @DavidGouveia, great example.