# Animate on tap in XNA (Windows Phone)

Tags: xna, c#, tweening

I'm trying to convert a AS3 game to C# / XNA and I'm looking for a way to animate a sprite.

More precisely, I want the sprite to rotate and scale a bit, then return to its starting position.

In AS3 I just use a tweening library and add a touch listener to the sprite, but I haven't been able to find something like this for XNA. How would you do something like that in C#?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm under the impression AS3 is a retained-mode API. You create a collection of objects - it draws and manages them for you. XNA, on the other hand, is an immediate-mode API. You are responsible for drawing things each frame, reading inputs each frame, keeping track of time, and so on.

Here is a complete game class to demonstrate what you want. Just paste it over the one in the default template, and add your own texture called "myTexture" to the content project.

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        IsMouseVisible = true;
    }

    Texture2D texture;

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("myTexture");
    }

    bool animating;
    const float totalTime = 1;
    float time;

    MouseState lastMouseState;

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();

        if(mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && lastMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
        {
            time = 0;
            animating = true;
        }
        else if(animating)
        {
            time += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
            if(time > totalTime)
            {
                time = 0;
                animating = false;
            }
        }

        lastMouseState = mouseState;
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        float alpha = time / totalTime; // from 0 to 1
        Vector2 position = new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2f, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2f);
        Vector2 origin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2f, texture.Height / 2f);
        float rotation = MathHelper.TwoPi* alpha;
        float scale = alpha < 0.5 ? MathHelper.SmoothStep(1, 2, alpha * 2f) : MathHelper.SmoothStep(2, 1, (alpha-0.5f) * 2f);

        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, null, Color.White, rotation, origin, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

        spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
```

(I've used `Mouse` here, and tested on Windows, but the code should work on the phone too (where `Mouse` is emulated). It should be easy enough to convert it to use [actual touch inputs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434208.aspx).)

On the one hand - this is an awful lot more code than you're probably used to. On the other hand - you get a lot more control and performance. Also - if you structure your code nicely and reuse things (admittedly this may take some practice) you can significantly reduce the amount of code you need to write in real-world situations, at least compared to the above.

And you could even go so far as to implement your own retained-mode style classes (eg: your own `Sprite` class). You can do this on top of an immediate-mode API. Whereas it's practically impossible to do the inverse: an immediate-mode style code on a retained-mode API.

(Personally I recommend just embracing the immediate-mode API. Let your own game model retain things - eg: a `Player` object that can draw itself, rather than a `Player` object that owns a `Sprite` object.)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not a part of the Microsoft XNA Framework so you have to create this behavior yourself. Here's what I would recommend.

1. First create a `Sprite` class which exposes the properties you need to animate, or simply expose these properties on your game object model classes, such as the `Player`. This is related to the difference between immediate-mode and retained-mode that Andrew talked about, so just pick the way you'd like to work.

   public class Sprite {
   public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
   public float Rotation { get; set; }
   public float Scale { get; set; }
   public Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
   public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch);
   }
2. Instead of managing the animations directly inside your game object model, create an external class that encapsulates and manages all types of animations. You could...

- Try an existing tweening library such as [TinyTween](https://gist.github.com/nickgravelyn/4953988) and see if it works for you (never used it).
- I like to treat this concept at an even higher level. What I usually do is create a class that can manage *any* sequence of actions, instead of just tweening properties. Then I create specific types of actions for tweening properties if I need it. Check the following answer for such an implementation "[How to chain actions/animations together and delay their execution?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/26887/11686)".

3. Finally, queue the animations on your manager! For example, with the `ProcessQueue` class I wrote about in the other answer, this would be done with something like:

```
 processQueue.Add(new Rotate(23f));
 processQueue.Add(new Scale(1.5f));
 processQueue.Add(new Move(new Vector2(400, 200));
```

Comment: Might as well share two useful types of processes: [Move](http://pastie.org/4631700) and [FloatInterpolation](http://pastie.org/4631734)