# How do I implement movement in a WPF Adventure game?

Tags: c#, movement, wpf

I'm working on making a short WPF adventure game.  The only major hurdle I have right now is how to animate objects on the screen correctly.  I've experimented with `DoubleAnimation` and `ThicknessAnimation` both enable movement of the character, but the speed is a bit erratic. The objects I'm trying to move around are `labels` in a `grid`, I'm checking the mouse's position in terms of the `canvas` I have the `grid` in.

Does anyone have any suggestions for coding the movement, while still allowing mouse clicks to pick up items when needed? It would be nice if I could continue using the Visual Studio GUI Editor.  **By the way, I'm fine with scrapping `labels` in a `grid` for a more ideal object to manipulate.**

Here's my movement code:

```
ThicknessAnimation ta = new ThicknessAnimation();
```

The event handling movement:

```
private void Hansel_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     ta.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
     ta.From = Hansel.Margin;

      double newX = Mouse.GetPosition(PlayArea).X;
      double newY = Mouse.GetPosition(PlayArea).Y;
      if (newX < Convert.ToDouble(Hansel.Margin.Left))
      {
           //newX = -1 * newX;
           ta.To = new Thickness(0, newY, newX, 0);

      }
      else if (newY < Convert.ToDouble(Hansel.Margin.Top))
      {
            newY = -1 * newY;
      }
      else
      {
            ta.To = new Thickness(newX, newY, 0, 0);
      }
      ta.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
      Hansel.BeginAnimation(Grid.MarginProperty, ta);
}
```

Screenshot with annotations:

[image: screenshot 1]

Screenshot with example movement:

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Can you maybe post a screenshot (perhaps with annotations) that shows what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Coming right up.

Comment: @AndrewRussell I've posted the screenshots with annotations.

Comment: What is your motivation for using WPF? Because it really isn't the best technology to be using for this. Why not XNA, for example?

Comment: The only reason I'm using WPF is I choose it since the professor said it would be more of a challenge than WinForms or Console.  He had mentioned XNA as more difficult to set up, but what I've learned so far about WPF is it makes the trivial hard and hard trivial.

Comment: If XNA is an option, I would suggest switching to that. Making a game in WPF is both convoluted and miles away from how the majority of games are *actually* programmed. (Except perhaps games like Minesweeper or card games.)

Comment: I agree with @AndrewRussell about WPF not being good for games. Here is a very involved WPF game example, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/174736/Snail-Quest . Maybe you can take a look at how the Snail Character's movement is implemented.

Comment: Yeah, movement definitely seems like more work than it should be.

Comment: @AndrewRussell are there any XNA specific obstacles I will most likely encounter in a game with movement, picking stuff up, and screen transitions?

Comment: @ZeroPhase XNA works very differently to WPF. Instead of a "retained" mode, where you create objects (instances of provided classes) and set their positions and properties, you have an "immediate" mode where you are given an `Update` and a `Draw` method, and each frame and are expected to redraw the screen yourself (you simply make your own classes). It's a bit more work initially - but it makes things a lot easier later on. Fortunately XNA comes with a lot of well-written [samples](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/).

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5459955/165500) and maybe [this one](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/35333/288). Also perhaps look at [this article](http://andrewrussell.net/2010/12/xna-spritebatch-in-silverlight-with-exen/) of mine that, while on another topic, does have a good description of retained vs immediate mode (using Silverlight as the retained example, which is like WPF).

Comment: @AndrewRussell Thanks alot, all of the youtube videos and documentation on similar issues should make the transition very doable.  I'll probably rebuild everything for WPF some time later.

Answer (score 2):

I've spent a lot of time worrying about WPF performance and animations when writing the WPF Mind Mapping app [NovaMind](http://www.novamind.com).

On Stackoverflow I've written down some [WPF animation best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4497963/10779). Maybe those can help you.

Regarding your question:

> I've experimented with `DoubleAnimation` and `ThicknessAnimation` both enable movement of the character, but the speed is a bit erratic.

Without knowing the details of your app it's hard to say why your animation is erratic. Most often the reason is the misuse of Effects such as a `DropDownShadow` or `Blur`.

If the element you are moving has Effects on them it's probably better to cache the visual in a Bitmap first or to move the Effect to the container.

One way to find out what's going on is to use the [WPF Performance Suite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/aa969767.aspx). Especially the Visual Profiler can show you easily if you have a CPU-bound issue or problems on the GPU.

As far as coding animations is concerned I had way more fun with [artefact animator](https://github.com/dotnetprojects/artefactanimator). Definitely worth a look as it makes it easier to define nice animations.

Overall I can only warn you that WPF is really not suited for game development. It might be fine for a prototype or hobby project and for a simple adventure game it might be okay but if you're interested in game development I would not invest any more time in WPF. One reason for this is that it's impossible to [get a constant framerate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733990/constant-framerate-in-wpf-for-game/7734405#7734405) which makes it pretty much useless for games.

Having written [a game](http://www.greenheartgames.com/app/game-dev-tycoon/) in HTML/JS myself since I've worked with WPF I see how much easier it can be. WPF is simply not suited.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've already started building in XNA though.