# Pattern for performing game actions

Tags: ai, design-patterns

Is there a generally accepted pattern for performing various actions within a game? A way a player can perform actions and also that an AI might perform actions, such as move, attack, self-destruct, etc.

I currently have an abstract BaseAction which uses .NET generics to specify the different objects that get returned by the various actions. This is all implemented in a pattern similar to the Command, where each action is responsible for itself and does all that it needs.

My reasoning for being abstract is so that I may have a single ActionHandler, and AI can just queue up different action implementing the baseAction. And the reason it is generic is so that the different actions can return result information relevant to the action (as different actions can have totally different outcomes in the game), along with some common beforeAction and afterAction implementations.

So... is there a more accepted way of doing this, or does this sound alright?

Comment: It sounds good, the question is what do you mean by queue? Most games have very quick response? "AI can queue up different action"

Comment: Good point. There is no queue. It just needs to know if is busy, and if not, execute action.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think there's *one* accepted way of implementing this concept, but I'd really like to share how *I* usually deal with this in my games. It's a bit of a combination of the **Command** design pattern and the **Composite** design pattern.

I have an abstract base class for actions which is nothing more than a wrapper around an `Update` method that gets called each frame, and a `Finished` flag to indicate when the action has finished running.

```cs
abstract class Action
{
    abstract void Update(float elapsed);
    bool Finished;
}
```

I also use the composite design pattern to create a type of actions that is capable of hosting and executing other actions. This too is an abstract class. Boils down to:

```
abstract class CompositeAction : Action
{
    void Add(Action action) { Actions.Add(action); }
    List<Action> Actions;
}
```

Then I have two implementations of composite actions, one for **parallel execution** and one for **sequential execution**. But the beauty is that since parallel and sequence are actions themselves, they can be *combined* in order to create more complex execution flows.

```
class Parallel : CompositeAction
{
    override void Update(float elapsed) 
    {
        Actions.ForEach(a=> a.Update(elapsed));
        Actions.RemoveAll(a => a.Finished);
        Finished = Actions.Count == 0;
    }
}
```

And the one that governs sequential actions.

```
class Sequence : CompositeAction
{
    override void Update(float elapsed) 
    {
        if (Actions.Count > 0) 
        {
            Actions[0].Update(elapsed);
            if (Actions[0].Finished)
                Actions.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        Finished = Actions.Count == 0;
    }
 }
```

With this in place it's simply a matter of creating concrete action implementations, and using the `Parallel` and `Sequence` actions to control the flow of execution. I'll end with an example:

```
// Create a parallel action to work as an action manager
Parallel actionManager = new Parallel();

// Send character1 to destination
Sequence actionGroup1 = new Sequence();
actionGroup1.Add(new MoveAction(character1, destination));
actionGroup1.Add(new TalkAction(character1, "Arrived at destination!"));
actionManager.Add(actionGroup1);

// Make character2 use a potion on himself
Sequence actionGroup2 = new Sequence();
actionGroup2.Add(new RemoveItemAction(character2, ItemType.Potion));
actionGroup2.Add(new SetHealthAction(character2, character2.MaxHealth));
actionGroup2.Add(new TalkAction(character2, "I feel better now!"));
actionManager.Add(actionGroup2);

// Every frame update the action manager
actionManager.Update(elapsed);
```

I have successfully used this system to drive all of the gameplay in a graphic adventure before, but it should probably work for pretty much anything. It was also simple enough to add other types of composite actions, which were used for creating execution loops and conditionals.

- See also: **[related answer here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/26887/11686)**.

Comment: That looks like a very nice solution. Out of curiosity, how then do you let the UI know what to draw? Do your game objects (like characters) contain state which is used to identify what happened for rendering purposes, or is it the action itself that does that?

Comment: Usually my actions only change the *state* of the entities, and any changes to the rendered output occur as a *consequence* of that state change, not by means of the actions themselves. For example, with an immediate-mode renderer there's no extra step required since the `Draw` method is already built on top of the state of the entity, and changes are automatic. In a retained-mode renderer like Flash, you could use the observable pattern to make changes to your entities propagate to the display objects, or make the connection manually inside the entity itself.

Comment: In the first situation, let's say that your `Character` class has a `Position` property, and a `Draw` method which reads what the current value of `Position` is and draws the correct image there. In this situation, you only need to update the value of `Position` that the result will be automatically seen on the screen.

Comment: The second situation is, when your `Character` has a `Position` property, but it delegates rendering to some sort of `Sprite` object which is being automatically rendered by a scene graph or something. In this situation you have to ensure that both the character's position and the sprite's position are always in sync, which involves a bit more work. Still, in either case, I don't see why the action manager should have anything to do with it. :)

Comment: Both methods have advantages and disadvantages.. I went with the second method for my 2D game, and I've regretted it at times because it's significantly more complicated to keep everything in sync. But there are advantages too, for instance when trying to detect which entity was clicked, or what should or not be drawn, because everything that will be rendered is contained within the same data structure instead of scattered between N entity types.

Comment: I'm a fan of this design pattern. It's really helping in my current game design. As you said, the beauty for me lies in the ability to chain these essentially endlessly. I already have at least one type of task coded as a CompositeAction itself made of CompositeActions and Actions and it works perfectly.